# DEV C++ header file list

Tags: c, dev-c++, compiler-services

From where does DEV C++ compiler includes header files in the source code like stdio.h, file.h, time.h ? Where is the folder which contains header files ? or these headers are included with different file extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you installed your dev c++. In my system this is the path

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.7.1\include\ssp
```